# i can not make using_markers(ie,to place somthing to the rviz)

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake using_markers
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['using_markers']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/liqiming/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131210-195602
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['using_markers'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['using_markers']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
that is the process i follow the tutorial of the web of RVIZ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108821/i-can-not-make-using_markers(ie,to-place-somthing-to-the-rviz)/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK.i know the reason why i can not make the package.i open a new terminal,but foget to add the  source /home/liqiming/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh .so i can not make the package.

---

Originally posted by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) with karma: 126 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on 2013-12-10**:
and the package should under the same directory of beginner_tutorials